# What is the alternate for drawPolygon in create JS ? Has this function been changed to something else?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, createjs, easeljs

Hope you're doing well and day has been good for you. My scenario is, we used create js [Create JS](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html) library for drawing shapes in our old Angular JS project and the code is below:

```
polygonGraphics(){
 var g = new createjs.Graphics();
 g.setStrokeStyle(2);
 g.beginStroke(createJS.Graphics.getRGB(255,0,0))
 g.beginFill("#34343");
 g.drawPolygon(0,0,customData)
}
```

This above code works fine in that old Angular Js project.

Now when I try to use this code in my new Angular 2 project, the compiler says, **g.drawPolygon** does not exist.
Has this been changed to something else in any of its versions? I tried finding but didn't get much info on this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: I did a quick search and the `Graphics` object has [`drawPolyStar`](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_drawPolyStar), no drawPolygon in sight though. Might have been custom functionality.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your comment. You're damn right. This is what they are using http://jsfiddle.net/k3rgk11e/2/. 

Any idea, how can I add this piece of code in my typescript and make it work?

Comment: Just insert that code after including the main script, exactly like the fiddle does.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly have found what code has been used. Here is the complete working code [drawPolygon](http://jsfiddle.net/k3rgk11e/2/.) and this is what I need. Do you have any idea, how can I add this code in my typescript file so that it can work by using g.drawPolygon()? Here is the code and working example is in the link.

```
    (createjs.Graphics.Polygon = function(x, y, points) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.points = points;
}).prototype.exec = function(ctx) {
    // Start at the end to simplify loop
    var end = this.points[this.points.length - 1];
    ctx.moveTo(end.x, end.y);
    this.points.forEach(function(point) {
        ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    });
};
createjs.Graphics.prototype.drawPolygon = function(x, y, args) {
    var points = [];
    if (Array.isArray(args)) {
        args.forEach(function(point) {
            point = Array.isArray(point) ? {x:point[0], y:point[1]} : point;
            points.push(point);
        });
    } else {
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(2);
        var px = null;
        args.forEach(function(val) {
            if (px === null) {
                px = val;
            } else {
                points.push({x: px, y: val});
                px = null;
            }
        });
    }
    return this.append(new createjs.Graphics.Polygon(x, y, points));
};
```

Thank you :)